# How can I set byobu to launch already split into four terminals, or quartered?

Tags: byobu

I like slipping out of the GUI and into TTY1 and would love to use byobu to automatically have the terminal split into four equal sized terminals. I haven't tried configuring anything in byobu yet but am unable to use the default ctrl+F2 to split vertically. I can use Shift+F2 to split horizontally though. I apologize if this has already been addressed, I tried finding a solution before posting but was unable to.

Answer (score 1):

All of the keybindings are only really "guaranteed" to work perfectly in gnome-terminal.  Other terminals (tty, putty, iterm, konsole, Windows cmd.exe) eat the control/shift/alt and f-keys in non-obvious ways.  That's the source of your ctrl-F2 problem -- the tty doesn't pass on ctrl-F2 to tmux properly.

As for splitting Byobu into 4 terminals, you can create a window layout and save it.  See the [byobu(1)](http://manpg.es/byobu.1) manpage for instructions.

*Full disclosure: I'm the author and maintainer of [Byobu](http://byobu.org).*